# customized report marketing cloud

Tags: sql, data, automation

I'm new to the marketing cloud and I want to create a custom report using data views within an activity in the automation studio. My objective is to automate the process because currently the data collection is done manually. I also want to customize the report by including only the specific data I need, without using the analytics builder.

The report should contain the following information:

Date/Time Sent
Emails Sent
Delivered
Deliverability Rate
Unique Opens
Open Rate
Total Clicks
Unique Clicks
Unique Click-Through Rate
CTOR
Undeliverables
Unsubscribes
Unsubscribe Rate

It's important to note that this report is generated on a weekly basis, covering a span of 7 days. However, emails may be sent on different days, so the "7 days" period for one email might not align with the same timeframe for another email.

To handle this, I understand that I'll need to break down the queries into smaller parts to avoid overloading the system. My question is whether it's possible to combine all these queries at the end into a single date extension, so that the final report doesn't become too scattered across multiple sources.

Thank you everyone!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.